# Scraping and saving text from html to csv via BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, dataframe, csv, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse and save all the information between all the `<p>` tags in ('div', class_='WYSIWYG articlePage') into first column and all the information from the `<span>` tag in ('div', class_='contentSectionDetails') into the second column in one .csv file (https://www.investing.com/news/stock-market-news/learjet-the-private-plane-synonymous-with-the-jetset-nears-end-of-runway-2419023). So the problem is that I have a thousands urls (URLs are generated based on numbers from the ALL_NUMBERS file) and I want to save this data in a single .csv file line by line from each url.

So I have the next code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import pandas as pd
import re
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime
import time

#--READ NAMES--
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2)\
    AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)\
    Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7'}

all_names = [] # TO KEEP ALL NAMES IN MEMORY

with open('ALL_NUMBERS.txt', 'r') as text_file:
    for line in text_file:
        line = line.strip()
        all_names.append(line)

url_template = 'https://www.investing.com/news/stock-market-news/learjet-the-private-plane-synonymous-with-the-jetset-nears-end-of-runway-{}'

all_urls = [] # TO KEEP ALL URLs IN MEMORY

with open("url_requests.txt", "w") as text_file:
    for name in all_names:
        url = url_template.format(name)
        print('url:', url)
        all_urls.append(url)
        text_file.write(url + "\n")

# --- read data ---
results_df = pd.DataFrame() #<-- initialize a results dataframe to dump/store the data you collect after each iteration
for name, url in zip(all_names, all_urls):
    # print('name:', name)
    # print('url:', url)
    r1 = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
    html = r1.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    results = soup.find('div', class_='WYSIWYG articlePage')
    para = results.findAll("p")
    results_2 = soup.find('div', class_='contentSectionDetails')
    para_2 = results_2.findAll("span")

data = []
ts = time.time()
st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')


temp_df = pd.DataFrame(data) #<-- temporary storing the data in a dataframe
results_df = results_df.append(temp_df).reset_index(drop=True) #<-- dumping that data into a results dataframe
results_df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False) #<-- writing the results dataframe to csv

testing = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
heading = testing.head(100)
discription = testing.describe()
print(heading)
```

I want to save it in .csv this way:

| Text | Time |
| --- | --- |
| `<p>` | `<span>` |
| `<p>` | `<span>` |
| ... | ... |

So I have a lot of mistakes:

```
    testing = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
  File "C:\Users\Jeffrey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 676, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Jeffrey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 448, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Jeffrey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 880, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Users\Jeffrey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1114, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "C:\Users\Jeffrey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1891, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 532, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

Maybe, someone knows how do it better...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas might be a bit overkill, you could just use the built in CSV library to write a row at a time:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2)\
    AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)\
    Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7'}
    
url_template = 'https://www.investing.com/news/stock-market-news/learjet-the-private-plane-synonymous-with-the-jetset-nears-end-of-runway-{}'

with open('ALL_NUMBERS.txt') as f_numbers, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(['Text', 'Time'])
    
    for number in f_numbers:
        url = url_template.format(number)
        print('url:', url)
        req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
        article = soup.find('div', class_='WYSIWYG articlePage')

        if article:
            text = ' / '.join(s.text  for s in article.find_all(['span', 'p']))   # grab all span and p inside article
            csd = soup.find('div', class_='contentSectionDetails')  # to grab the time inside the span
            csv_output.writerow([text, csd.span.text])
```

Giving you `output.csv` containing:

```
Text,Time
"© Reuters.  Why Platinum ETFs Are Starting to Draw More Attention / Platinum exchange traded funds have rallied over the past year, with the white metal hovering near its highest level in six years. Investors continue to pile in. Over the past three months, the Aberdeen Standard Platinum Shares ETF (NYSEArca: PPLT) has increased 43.1%% and the GraniteShares Platinum Trust (PLTM) has added 44.5%. Money managers have started pouring [...] / The post Why Platinum ETFs Are Starting to Draw More Attention appeared first on ETF Trends.","Feb 15, 2021 12:00PM ET"
```

Comment: Yes! It works! Thank you! And how can I avoid an empty pages? Cause if the page is empty, there is a mistake:
```text = ' / '.join(s.text for s in article.find_all(['span', 'p']))  # grab all span and p inside article
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'```

Comment: Just add `if article:` and indent the code below,  should work fine

Comment: Yes. Great! Thank you!

Comment: Martin, hello!
May be do you know how to decode the result into base64 format with utf-8?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Do you mean write base64 encoded utf-8 to the CSV file? The whole row? Both columns?  Adding `encoding='utf-8'` will save the entries with utf-8 encoding to your CSV. For base64 use something like `b64 = base64.b64encode(text.encode('utf-8'))`

Comment: Write the final code below in the comment. And I really don't know how can I speed up program execution. Cause for 450K pages it will works for about 26 days... May be I need use smth like Threading?

Comment: An asyncio approach would be your best bet, although you might find the website might stop you.

Comment: So, after 9K pages the website didn't stop me :D
Thank you, Martin!

Answer (score 0):

Final version:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import base64

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2)\
    AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)\
    Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36',
           'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7'}

url_template = 'https://www.investing.com/news/stock-market-news/learjet-the-private-plane-synonymous-with-the-jetset-nears-end-of-runway-{}'

with open('ALL_NUMBERS.txt') as f_numbers, open('outputNews_base64.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding = 'utf-8') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(['Text', 'Time'])

    for number in f_numbers:
        url = url_template.format(number)
        print('url:', url)
        req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
        article = soup.find('div', class_='WYSIWYG articlePage')

        if article:
            text = ' / '.join(s.text for s in article.find_all(['span', 'p']))  # grab all span and p inside article
            csd = soup.find('div', class_='contentSectionDetails')  # to grab the time inside the span
            b64text = base64.b64encode(text.encode('utf-8'))
            b64time = base64.b64encode(csd.span.text.encode('utf-8'))
            csv_output.writerow([b64text, b64time])
```